# Div still visible with background-color: transparent;

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a div transparent so only the box-shadow is visible.

CSS

```
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 300px rgba(255, 000, 048, 1);
    border-radius: 300px;
}
```

This is the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G4wg.png

As you can see the circle is the same color as the background

What I actually want is that you see the shadow effect through the circle

(I offset the shadow)
imagine something like this without that circle https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32Y7.png

Comment: Basically you want a colour to radiate outwards https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a radial-gradient:

```
.circle {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgb(255, 000, 048), #000 300px);
}
```

Here's another solution, but it wont work as well as the first suggestion.

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 000, 048);
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: blur(300px);
}
```

Comment: that feel when i see 048 and automagically see a octal number exception. luckily this is css.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misinterpreted your question before. Do you need something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.circle{
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: red; 
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red, white);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example here:http://tpcg.io/zod3S3

Comment: right now i have placed the div outside the screen and added an offset to the shadow which give me the result i wanted but maybe your idea is cleaner.

result: https://i.imgur.com/h3ajZ05.png

Comment: @quintendc - I can't imagine that being very responsive if the screensize changes (Not sure if that's a valid scenario). I believe my proposed solution is cleaner and more responsive. Please mark my answer as correct or upvote if you think it helped :) 

Feel free to ask if you have any further questions or need any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're looking for, but try this:

```
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 300px rgba(255, 000, 048, 1);
  border-radius: 300px;
}
```